# Calculating the mean between several raster layers, with NoData values

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, landsat, landsat-8

I have several Landsat 8 scenes from which i have derived the surface temperature. To obtain an average, I would like to generate the mean between all my scenes. However, prior to this I am planing to delete the cloud cover from each image.

My next step would then be to perform the average of each cell value, ignoring NoData values. That is, if I have 6 scenes in total, and one of them has the value NoData, that cell should calculate the mean using only the other 5 scenes.

How could I get this done? If I am right, the Raster Calculator tool is not an option since it will only perform calculations in those areas where all the layers overlap.

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: Further to @BERA's comment, assuming it's ArcMap (since you mention Raster Calculator) do you you have the spatial analyst extension?

Comment: Hello, I am using ArcMap 10.1, and I have spatial analyst extension. My solution so far has been to use the cell statistics tool, which seems to do the job.